# Does anyone know why I'm getting a completely black geotiff as a result of this shapefile cut out of another geotiff in rasterio?

Tags: python, shapefile, geotiff, rasterio

I am using rasterio to cut out the shape of a lake outlined in my shapefile from a geotiff. When using a shapefile of a singular lake with a geotiff, this works perfectly, but not when cutting out a geotiff of a single lake with a different shapefile that contains a lot of different lake outlines. I'm wondering if there is a problem with the way my code is written or the files I'm using?

Here's my code:

```
import rasterio
import rasterio.mask
import fiona

with fiona.open("liag_shapes/liag_shapes.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    features = [feature["geometry"]for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open("lakesimcoe11.tif") as src:
    out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, features, filled=True,
crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()

out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open("new_test.tif", "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```